# Adding View Inside Listview

Tags: android, listview

[image: Charge Tab]

Hello Guys ,

I had edited my question with the screenshot, as you can see on the charge tab there is listview ,there is several block one below the other ,in the screenshot you can see 1 , with the truck number and charge 1 and charge 2 ,and below that there is another block items with same view as block 1.

What i need to do ,charge(i.e below LR No.) is coming from the webservice , there can be any number of charges , if there is 5 charges applied to truck number then it should be added below  detention layout (i.e charge 2) .As (similiar to Charge 2 is added below charge 1)

BaseAdapter Class:

```
public class ApprovalAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<ApprovalPogo> list;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;


    public ApprovalAdapter( Context context,List<ApprovalPogo> list) {

        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
    class Viewholder{
        TextView truck_name;
        TextView lr_no;

        Button btn_approve;
        Button btn_reject;
        Button btn_approve_status_change;

        Button btn_approve2;
        Button btn_reject2;
        Button btn_chnge_status_two;

        TextView extra_height;
        TextView detention;




    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final Viewholder viewholder;

        if(convertView==null){
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_approvals, parent, false);
            viewholder=new Viewholder();

            viewholder.truck_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appr_txt_truck);
            viewholder.lr_no = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appr_lrNo);

            viewholder.extra_height = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.extra_height);
            viewholder.detention = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_detention);

            viewholder.btn_approve=(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.approve_btn);
            viewholder.btn_reject=(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.reject_btn);
            viewholder.btn_approve_status_change = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status_change_btn);


            viewholder.btn_approve2=(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status_charge_two_approve_btn);
            viewholder.btn_reject2=(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status_charge_two_reject_btn);
            viewholder.btn_chnge_status_two=(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.status_change_charge_two_btn);

            viewholder.btn_approve.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String time=getTime();

                    viewholder.btn_approve.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    viewholder.btn_reject.setVisibility(View.GONE);



                    viewholder.btn_approve_status_change.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewholder.btn_approve_status_change.setText("Accepted on "+time);
                    viewholder.btn_approve_status_change.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.approval_change_status_backg);

                }
            });
            viewholder.btn_reject.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String time=getTime();
                    viewholder.btn_reject.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    viewholder.btn_approve.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    viewholder.btn_approve_status_change.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewholder.btn_approve_status_change.setText("Rejected on "+time);
                    viewholder.btn_approve_status_change.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.approval_reject_chng_status);
                }
            });

            viewholder.btn_approve2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String time=getTime();
                    viewholder.btn_approve2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    viewholder.btn_reject2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    viewholder.btn_chnge_status_two.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewholder.btn_chnge_status_two.setText("Accepted on "+time);
                    viewholder.btn_chnge_status_two.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.approval_change_status_backg);
                }
            });
            viewholder.btn_reject2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String time=getTime();
                    viewholder.btn_reject2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    viewholder.btn_approve2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    viewholder.btn_chnge_status_two.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewholder.btn_chnge_status_two.setText("Rejected on "+time);
                    viewholder.btn_chnge_status_two.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.approval_reject_chng_status);
                }
            });





            convertView.setTag(viewholder);

        }else{
            viewholder=(Viewholder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        viewholder.truck_name.setText(list.get(position).getTruckName()) ;
        viewholder.lr_no.setText(list.get(position).getLrNmbr()) ;
//        viewholder.btn_approve_status_change.setText(list.get(position));
//
//        for(int i=0;i<list.get(position).getApprovalSubListPogos().size();i++){
//            viewholder.btn_approve_status_change.setText(list.get(position).getApprovalSubListPogos().get(i).getStatusChange()) ;
//            viewholder.extra_height.setText(list.get(position).getApprovalSubListPogos().get(i).getHeight()) ;
//            viewholder.detention.setText(list.get(position).getApprovalSubListPogos().get(i).getHeight()) ;
//
//
//        }




        Config.colorFont(context, null, viewholder.truck_name, null);
        Config.colorFont(context, null, viewholder.lr_no, null);
        Config.colorFont(context, null, viewholder.extra_height, null);
        Config.colorFont(context, null, viewholder.detention, null);

        Config.colorFont(context, null, null ,viewholder.btn_approve);
        Config.colorFont(context, null, null, viewholder.btn_reject);
        Config.colorFont(context, null, null, viewholder.btn_approve_status_change);

        Config.colorFont(context, null, null, viewholder.btn_approve2);
        Config.colorFont(context, null,null, viewholder.btn_reject2);
        Config.colorFont(context, null,null, viewholder.btn_chnge_status_two);



        return convertView;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled()
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public String getTime(){
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"+5.5));
        Date currentLocalTime = cal.getTime();

        System.out.println(currentLocalTime);

        DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");

        String localTime = date.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

//        date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
//        String localTime = date.format(currentLocalTime);


        return localTime;
    }


    public void findDuplicate(){


        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){

            for(int j=i+1;j<list.size();j++){

                if(list.get(j).getTruckName().equalsIgnoreCase(list.get(i).getTruckName())){

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

single_row_xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/truck_rounded_view"

    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:background="@drawable/approval_header"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"

                android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/appr_txt_truck"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Truck  MH01BQ4111"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/approval_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/approval_margin"
            android:textSize="@dimen/approval_header_size"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/darkgray"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/appr_lrNo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="LR 788691"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/approval_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/approval_margin"
            android:textSize="@dimen/approval_header_size"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/approval_rl_top"
            android:textColor="@color/darkgray"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        <!--<View
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/approval_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/approval_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/approval_margin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/approval_divider_height"
            android:background="@color/white" />-->

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/approval_rl_top"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/approval_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/approval_margin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/appr_charge_one"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Charge 1"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_approval_txt"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button

                android:id="@+id/approve_btn"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/approval_btn_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/approval_btn_height"
                android:background="@drawable/aprroval_aprrove_backg"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/approval_padding_left"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

                android:textSize="@dimen/approval_text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="APPROVE" />


            <Button
           android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/status_change_btn"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/approval_status_chnege_width"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/approval_btn_height"
                android:background="@drawable/approval_change_status_backg"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/approval_margin"


                android:textSize="@dimen/approval_text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="Accepted on 3:00 PM" />




        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/approval_rl_top"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/approval_margin"
          android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/approval_margin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/extra_height"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Extra Height - Rs 200"

            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_approval_txt"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/reject_btn"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/approval_btn_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/approval_btn_height"
                android:text="Reject"
                android:textSize="@dimen/approval_text_size"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/approval_padding_left"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@drawable/approval_reject_backg"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>




        </RelativeLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/approval_rl_top"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/approval_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/approval_margin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/approval_divider_height"
            android:background="@color/white" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/approval_rl_top"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/approval_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/approval_margin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/charge_two"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Charge 2 "
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/txt_approval_txt"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button

                android:id="@+id/status_charge_two_approve_btn"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/approval_btn_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/approval_btn_height"
                android:background="@drawable/aprroval_aprrove_backg"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/approval_padding_left"

                android:textSize="@dimen/approval_text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="APPROVE" />


            <Button
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/status_change_charge_two_btn"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/approval_status_chnege_width"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/approval_btn_height"
                android:background="@drawable/approval_change_status_backg"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/approval_padding_left"


                android:textSize="@dimen/approval_text_size"

                android:text="Rejected on 3:00 PM" />



        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/approval_rl_top"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/approval_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/approval_margin"

            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/approval_margin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_detention"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Detention - Rs 200"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_approval_txt"


            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button

                android:id="@+id/status_charge_two_reject_btn"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/approval_btn_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/approval_btn_height"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="REJECT"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:background="@drawable/approval_reject_backg"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/approval_padding_left"
                />

         </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use Nestedscrollview as parent of your layout

Comment: that means expandable listview  or any other @Barnali Bhattacharjee

Comment: how we can achieve it , do you have sample code ?

Comment: http://www.journaldev.com/9942/android-expandablelistview-example-tutorial refer this link@BarnaliBhattacharjee

Answer (score 2):

please use Expandable ListView to better use.

[for more information and example about Expandable listview](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)

Comment: Or even better, use a RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to put scrollable things into scrollable things, and you usually shouldn't need to in the first place. This won't work most of the time.

Comment: ,I need to do this